# Mail Not Sending From Server, Told To Edit

Tags: centos, imap, plesk

Recently there was a problem sending mail from a server. When researched into it, there was an segmentation(11) fault error.

I was directed to this article http://kb.parallels.com/en/260, and told to update the fs.file-max /etc/sysctl.conf. The problem is, there is no fs.file-max in the file. A little more background on the problem:

- Server Centos 5.5
- Plesk 10
- Emails not sending from a mailbox that has 4 Gigs worth of email(if
  that matters).

Does anyone have a clue how to fix or a better way of finding out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is, there is no fs.file-max in the file.
```

The article you are referring to would suggest adding this parameter, it doesn't say this parameter is in the file:

"... it should be changed by ***adding*** the following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf ..."